# Strange transparency change

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, camera, eevee-render-engine

I have some strange behavior: I want to render (animate) small semi-transparent spheres inside large semi-transparent sphere, but small ones at some point change their color/transparency (see gif). It seems like there is a certain distance from camera/angle, when material changes.

[image: Gif]

These are materials on both objects:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The change happens when little spheres are outside/inside the big sphere. Materials do not change at all.

Comment: @joshsanfelici They are actually inside all the time

Answer (score 0):

Alpha blend is a recipe for trouble if you have more than one face it is working with. Use alpha hashed instead. If this is too fuzzy, turn up samples or switch to Cycles rendering.